# Angular: Show/Hide text using compositionstart event binding

Tags: angular, events, text, composition, event-binding

I am having some trouble getting some text to hide/show based on simple logic. I think it has to do with the event binding I am using. But I am not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

the HTML code

```
<h3 *ngIf='showFilter'
    (compositionstart)='toggleFilter()'>Filter by: {{listFilter}}
</h3>
```

The logic for the hide/show

```
toggleFilter(): void{
    if(this.listFilter != ''){
        this.showFilter == true;
    }else{
        this.showFilter == false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the event get triggered at all (did you try console.log() in the function)? Why not: `(compositionstart)="showFilter = !showFilter"` ?

Comment: I'll try logging it now, and update in a few. I will also try your tip.

Comment: @Meir It doesn't look like it is triggering at all.

Comment: So maybe this event is: 1. Not supported by your browser?. 2. Not tracked by angular? 3. Not triggered when you think it should? Try obtaining the element itself (via ElementRef.nativeElement) and add an event listener to see if it works (element.addEventListener('compositionstart', handlerFN)

Comment: I managed to find another way to do it. Instead of trying to base it off a function. So instead of <h3 *ngIf='showFilter' ... </h3> I changed it to <h3 *ngIf='listFilter' ... </h3> listFilter being the variable for the filter itself. I am assuming this works because it will only show if the listFilter is not null, thus being true.

Comment: Managed to find a fix, instead of doing the whole  (compositionstart)='toggleFilter()'>Filter by: {{listFilter}} part, just do <h3 *ngIf='listFilter'>Filter by: {{listFilter}}</h3> it works because listFilter is null and JS sees that as false.